# "Notice: Undefined variable" but variable is declared in a function

Tags: php, function, variables, pdo, undefined

I am going though my site and trying to make it more future proof and cleaner so converting a lot of things to common functions.

I have a particular function that takes the the users session (session name is the username) and it runs a query on the database which fetches all of the other data for that user.

I wish to use the `userID` in some parts but i am getting the error "Notice: Undefined variable"

This is an example:

```
function getUserData_FromSession() {
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "root"; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "06vids";

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
    try 
    { 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "' . $_SESSION['user']. '"');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $userid = $row['id'];
    $usernameuser = $row['username'];
    }

}
 }
```

That function is in a functions file that is included in a page, on that page i do this:

```
 getUserData_FromSession();

 if ($userid == $userbuildid) {
    $editenabled = 'edity';
} else if ($userid !== $userbuildid) {
    $editenabled = 'editx';
}
```

This gives the error that $userid is undeclared. If i have the query actually on the same page then it works fine, but i dont want to have loads of querys popping up everywhere.

Comment: initalize $userid="";  at starting level

Comment: either you use a return type for userid or include your function file like include('./includes/yourfuntion.php'); where you want $userid value.

Comment: Sorry to say, but your code neither future proof nor clean. And not even close

Comment: Well done for using PDO! If you can change this to use parameterisation, you'll be much safer - this is the best way to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @halfer are you serious? you call it "much"? Means at the moment there is any protection at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is defined in a local scope of the function and will never be accessible outside of it. Unless of course you define it as global.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

So a quick fix would look like this:

```
function getUserData_FromSession() {
    global $userid;
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables used inside functions are not valid outside! That is actually a good thing, because you do not need to remember which names were already used as variables if you are inside a function.

Functions do return a value. You have not used that feature, but you should.

```
function whatever() {
    $variable = "bar"; // no effect outside this function!
    return "foo";
}

echo $variable; // Notice: undefined variable

$variable = whatever();
echo $variable; // outputs foo

$anythingelse = whatever();
echo $anythingelse; // outputs foo
```

Comment: For clarity, it's worth pointing out that the second case of `$variable` could in fact be any variable, and does not have to be the same as the first.

Answer (score 1):

The `$userid` variable doesn't exist outside your function scope. If you want to use it outside the function, perhaps you should `return` it.

```
function test() {
   $bar = 'stuff';  // references to local scope variable
}

echo $bar;
```

The above code will also output the `Undefined variable` error.

If you want the `$bar` variable to be accessible outside your function, you can do:

```
function test() {
    $bar = 'stuff'; 
    return $bar;
}

$bar = test(); // $bar could be any other variable
echo $bar; // => stuff
```

Note that the variable name doesn't matter. That is, the `$bar` in `$bar = test();` could be `$foo`, `$baz` or `$bak`. We're only assigning the return value of the function to a variable, so the name doesn't matter.

If for some reason you can't use the above approach, then you may declare the variable as a `global`, like so:

```
function test() {
    global $bar;
    $bar = 'stuff'; 
}

test();
echo $bar; // => stuff
```

It's generally considered bad practice to use `global`s, but this gets the job done.

It's a good thing that you use PDO for querying the database, but to make it even better, you could use parameterized queries. It helps you prevent [SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com/php).